# ImageIO import not working Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I'm a bit of a Clojure novice, but I don't understand what's wrong about my code.

The code bellow to my knowledge should set `img`to a new `BufferedImage` object.

```
(import javax.imageio.ImageIO)
(import java.io.File)
(def img (ImageIO/read (File. "C:\\input.png")))
```

However, when I execute `lein run` I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: ImageIO, compiling:(fstego/core.clj:8:14)
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine in my REPL. Could you paste the `ns` declaration on top of `src/fstego/core.clj`?

Comment: `(ns fstego.core
        (:gen-class))`

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you can run

```
lein run
```

without a -main method, so here is some sample code:

**project.clj**

```
  (defproject testi "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
     :main fstego.core
     :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]])
```

**src/fstego/core.clj**

```
  (ns fstego.core
    (:import [javax.imageio ImageIO])
    (:import [java.io File]))


  (defn -main[& args]
   (if-let [ path (first args) ]
    (let[ img (ImageIO/read (File. path))]
     (println 
      "Input Image has the following dimensions: " 
      (.getWidth img) "x" (.getHeight img)))
    (println "No image")))
```

And then

```
lein run <path_to_image>
```

Should output something like:

```
Input Image has the following dimensions:  251 x 60
```

**Edit**
Why was the java import not found when running *lein run*?

Before running the main method of your namespace, the compilation phase is executed and without the specific directive, your namespace is compiled ahead of time (called aot), to Java. 
To disable the feature, you need to add this to your project.clj

```
:main ^:skip-aot fstego.core
```

If you clean up the target folder and execute *lein run* again the import will be found wherever you add them.

If you do not specify skipping this task, or if you want to call your main method directly from a jar file, the lifecycle is different.

Running the namespace means the code is executed just as it would be in the REPL, thus the import calls are executed, and the referenced classes are found.

Running the main method straight from the compiled bytecode means the call to import is not included in the bytecode, thus ignored, thus the call to ImageIO fails to find the class properly.

Comment: Okay, so, found the problem. Apparently, for whatever reason, if I did the imports in the main function it won't work. When I do them in the namespace declaration, it works fine.

Comment: Added some insight as to why ImageIO was not found.